# how to remove index in php response

Tags: php

I've a variable `$response` which is an array and contains the below response

```
"example": {
     "1": {
         "name": "stan",
         "city": "NY"
      },
     "2": {
         "name": "wilson",
         "city": "FL"
      }
 }
```

How can I remove the indexing from the response?

Comment: try `array_values()` to flush the indexes, or explain in more details :)

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
array_values($response);
```

This resets all the keys/indexes of the array.